# Visualizing a XML as a tree

Tags: xml, tree, visualize

I come to you with a bit of a soft-question that might seem a little odd to some.

Currently, I'm trying to show my younger brother how `XML` documents work. He's not an idiot (or, I like to think he isn't) so he's grasped the basics about elements and attributes.

What he's having a hard time grasping is how it all forms as a tree. I've tried drawing the tree on paper for him, and explaining how elements related by parenthood, but whenever I check if he's got it down, he fails.

What I wonder is, if there exists a Eclipse (the editor we have at hand) pluggin or some function that would visually represent the tree, in a drawn manner, of the `XML` document he's got in front of him?

Something like...

[image]

...that!

With his current elements on it?

Does such functionality exist?

**Note:** My rep is too low to use the tag `soft-question`. Forgive that.

Comment: Don't worry about "soft-question", on SO [we don't use such tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) but question is off-topic because it asks to recommend a tool (an off-site resource). I don't remember name but there is a specific StackExchange site for this kind of questions. Anyway: there are many plugins like that: for example [<oXygen/> XML Plugin](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/eclipse_plugin.html).

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I should have been a little more specific... The reason Eclipse is the tool at hand, is because Eclipse is free. That plugin is a lot... less free. If you catch my drift!

Comment: Very good reason to avoid that one! ;) Did you try [this](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/09/08/tree.html)? There is code to write and it's not such easy (at least for me) but it can be automated.

Comment: I like this one, and I think it'll get the job done! Thanks!